# Does Python import all modules in a module path?

Tags: python, import, module

Let's assume I have the following structure.

```
main.py
    /mod1
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
        /mod2
            __init__.py
            mod2.py
```

And I have the following line in `main.py`.

```
import mod1.mod2
```

In this case does `mod1` also get imported?

Comment: Note that `__init__.py` files need not be empty. If they aren't empty they are executed during importing. This means that `mod1` *must* be imported in your case because `mod1/__init__.py` could setup some resource or stuff like that required by (e.g.) `mod2`.  Also modules have reeferences to their packages, so the parent modules must be imported for the references to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; `mod1` is imported as well, and you can access `mod1` solely as `mod1` within your code if you do not write an alias like this `import mod1.mod2 as mod2`.

Python needs to import the modules consecutively so that it is able to import last module. You can test this by putting print statements in your `__init__.py` files

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try this in the interpreter:

```
import os.path
dir
os
```

As this shows, `os` is present in the main namespace.